# How to train a regressor model on data that has duplicate subjects but different records for each?

Tags: machine-learning, data, training, data-science-model

I am working on a dataset that is as follows (just an example):

| prop_subj | prop_comp | bed_subj | bath_comp | sqft_subj | sqft_comp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | 2 | 1 | 1002 | 1006 |
| A | C | 2 | 2 | 1002 | 1075 |
| A | D | 2 | 2 | 1002 | 1000 |
| B | G | 2 | 1 | 1002 | 978 |
| B | F | 2 | 2 | 1002 | 1200 |
| B | D | 2 | 1 | 1002 | 960 |

Let's just say a prop_subj can have multiple prop_comp. For training a regressor model using such dataset, I was wondering whether I can treat As, Bs, and so on as a group by assigning a random number to each and passing it to the model such that the model can determine the group as just one property.

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Hi and welcome to the community:)
A couple of quick questions in regards to the OP.

1. There seem to be a repeating column name prop_subj?
2. Do you want to treat ear row as a single property or you plan to do something else?
3. What's the target variable here
4. What is the grouping of A's and B's. Is this grouping meant along a row or along. A column

Comment: Google categorical encoding. Start with one-hot encoding, move on to more advanced encoders depending on the problem.

Comment: @Polymath thanks! and I should have been more precise with the example. 1) Sorry for the typo - I updated the table. 2) But what I am trying to achieve is a way to train the model such that the A's, B's, and so on would be treated by the model as a group instead of an individual row because that's associated with a single subject. 3) The target (not shown in that table) is price_diff as I am trying to predict: the difference in price. 4) grouping is along the column. So each property has a comp - multiple prop can have same comp. Think of A's B's as address (these won't go into training).

Answer (score 1):

Assigning random number might not be ideal as number have a natural order. For example, if B is 1, C is 100, D is 10. The model will treat `B<D<C`, which shouldn't be the case.

One-Hot Encoder would be a better solution. It converts the categorical column to columns of `1` and `0`, which will be independent when fitting into the regression model. If you are using pandas, you can use [`pd.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) to achieve that.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['A', 'B', 2, 1, 1002, 1006], ['A', 'C', 2, 2, 1002, 1075], ['A', 'D', 2, 2, 1002, 1000]], columns=['prop_subj', 'prop_comp', 'bed_subj', 'bath_comp', 'sqft_subj', 'sqft_comp'])
df

  prop_subj prop_comp  bed_subj  bath_comp  sqft_subj  sqft_comp
0         A         B         2          1       1002       1006
1         A         C         2          2       1002       1075
2         A         D         2          2       1002       1000


df = pd.concat([df,pd.get_dummies(df['prop_comp'], prefix='prop_comp')],axis=1)
df = df.drop(['prop_comp'],axis=1)
df

    prop_subj   bed_subj    bath_comp   sqft_subj   sqft_comp   prop_comp_B prop_comp_C prop_comp_D
0          A           2           1         1002        1006             1           0           0
1          A           2           2         1002        1075             0           1           0
2          A           2           2         1002        1000             0           0           1
```

If you are using sklearn, you can refer to the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html).